# importing table using mysql console on localhosted WAMP

Tags: mysql, import, console

this is what I use in MySQL console (WAMP) (no password, as it is local)

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p dbase < table.sql
```

or this

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p dbase < C:\path\to\table.sql
```

this is what I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -u root -p dbase < table.sql' at line 1
```

what may cause this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're using is meant to be run outside of the mysql shell.  If you just `exit` out of the mysql shell and enter the same command, it should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer - just to point out - my problem was caused by using WAMP link, which calls MySQL server console directly, so any access back to prompt was not possible ... well .. just read my answer, if you wish - again thank you for taking time to answer

Answer (score 0):

OK - step by step - since, if someone is not used to it, any omission may get that "someone" lost.

---

**remote nix server**:

1. connect to mysql cli (command line interface) using e.g. Putty - type in: mysql -u user -pyourpassword
2. now you are connected to MySQL server and you can use e.g. LOAD INFILE command etc.
3. "exit" gets you back to "-bash" so you can use, e.g. database importing - just type:  mysql -u root -p hmvc < table.sql

---

**local WAMP - (setup: WAMP2.2 - Apache2.2.21 - MySQL5.5.20)**

**case I**: using Windows "command prompt"

1. change directory to the one, where your mysql resides within WAMP root, e.g.:
   C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin
2. connect to mysql cli: 
   mysql -u user -pyourpassword
3. now you are in, so you can use e.g. LOAD INFILE command etc.
4. "exit" gets you back to "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin>" so you can use, e.g. database importing: 
   mysql -u root -p hmvc < table.sql 
   etc.

**case 2**: using mysql cli directly

WAMP offers a link to it in its tray icon command collection

link is called: MySQL console

it calls mysql server diretly by invoking C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin\mysql.exe

1. you can use all MySQL commands right away, like e.g. LOAD INFILE
2. you cannot import/dump database using this console
   if you try to exit, MySQL console will do just that - it will exit (window gets closed)

I hope it will you some time.